Proving a series limit using the dominated convergence theorem
As part of an exercise from our calculus homework, we need to prove the following relationship using dominated convergence theorem for the counting measure:
$$ 
\lim_{t \rightarrow 1}  \frac{-4t}{(t^2-1)^2} +4t \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1+t^2)^2-4t^2} = \frac{3}{4}
$$
I found out that the first term is exactly the first summand of the series with the "-" sign. So my idea was to examine the series $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{4t}{(2n+1+t^2)^2-4t^2}$, but I couldn't find a solution because after simplifying the series it was still not easy to evaluate exactly.
Would anyone be so kind as to give me a hint on how to proceed with this task? Thank you very much.

Why would to evaluate the series exactly when you are specifically told to apply DCT?

@geetha290krm You are right. I tried to represent the first term as a series, until I found out that it's the first term of the series with the negative sign and became too focused on exploiting that fact.

The limit of the $n$-term is equal $${1\over n(n+2)}={1\over 2n}-{1\over 2(n+2)}$$ So the sum is equal $1/2+1/4.$
